# What compositor does Ubuntu 20.10 use by default

Tags: gnome, 20.10, wayland, compositing

I have done a clean minimal install of Ubuntu 20.10 in a VMWare Player virtual machine, running on an Intel Core i9 based PC.
I would like to know which compositor is used by default.
I am using the default desktop, which I think is Gnome.
Possibly it is mutter, as `ps -ax | grep -i mutter`, shows:

```
78825 ?        Sl     1:52 /usr/bin/Xwayland :0 -rootless -noreset -accessx -core -auth /run/user/1000/.mutter-Xwaylandauth.GPDI20 -listen 4 -listen 5 -displayfd 6 -listen 7
99042 pts/3    R+     0:00 grep --color=auto -i Mutter
```

Please can someone confirm if it is mutter, or if not, which one is used?

Comment: From the release notes. At the heart of Ubuntu 20.10 is the GNOME 3.38 release. This is the latest version of the open source desktop environment and it adds a wealth of improvements throughout the whole desktop stack.  https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2020/05/ubuntu-20-10-release-features

Comment: You used the term compositor never heard that before. It is called a DE or desktop Environment.

Comment: [GNOME Shell's architecture](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Technology) doesn't split out the compositor - it's a part of GNOME Shell (it is indeed mutter, but you won't see it running separately). What exactly are you trying to determine here?

Comment: @muru You may want to develop your comment into an answer.

Comment: @vanadium waiting to see what exactly OP wants to find out. If OP's looking to detect the desktop environment, there's a dupe for that

Comment: @muru I am trying to find out the best way of achieving an unusual  split of user focus between applications, and I am thinking maybe a custom compositor may be the way of achieving this.

Comment: @SimonBagley you cannot use a custom compositor with GNOME Shell, you'll have to ditch that altogether and use something like MATE or Xfce.

Answer (score 2):

@muru answered my question - the compositor is mutter. Looks like I was going down the wrong path with the Gnome desktop anyway. Looks like I need to use MATE or Xfce in order to use a custom compositor.